# Retriving Last Used data in winform C#

Tags: c#, database, winforms, sqlite

I've developed one project in`winform` with c#. There i've used `listbox`,`datagridview` and `textbox`es . What i want to do is that, in the middle of execution accidentally if user closed the `winform` , we need to save those data and give it back when user restarts the project. For this , its better to use database or any other choice is there ? If we are using database how can we store those data dynamically ? is that better to use `sqlite` ?
Can Anyone give me an idea ?

Comment: Is this a single-user or a multi-user app, i.e. will more than one user need access to the same database, or is it one database per user? Sqlite is only appropriate if it's single-user.

Comment: its single user ly , how can we do that using sqlite ? i'm new to sqlite ...

Comment: if I am not wrong managing state of controls on close event is not a better idea, but if you are still very much interested you need to serialize state on close event and deserialize when this form is opened.

Comment: Using a database may be overkill for your needs. XML serialization may satisfy your needs better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had to do something like this, I thought it would be best to use:
this is a short way of using the settings, just for you c:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName != "")
        {
            TextBox1.text = Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName;
            //And so on
        }
    }



    private void Form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName = //things you want to save;
        //Do it for the rest aswell
    }
```

> "BlockquoteThis is a very general question.You need to serialize the state by yourself somewhow but that depend on many things in your project.
>
> Alternatively you can also take a look at Settings
>
> this might also be helpful" ~Kyle

PS: My reputation isn't high enough to comment, so thats why i had to do it like this.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very general question.You need to serialize the state by yourself somewhow but that depend on many things in your project.

Alternatively you can also take a look at [Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[this](http://www.sorrowman.org/c-sharp-programmer/save-user-settings.html) might also be helpful

Comment: based on those links i get to know that we can store the details of location,font color and text box values etc, but not the datagridview values . Is that also possible with this ?

Comment: @kavithai_kannan considering your datagridview values which can be huge it is better to perform XML Serialization

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking about when the user closes a single form or closes the application entirely?

If you just mean closing the single form, you can have the form data stored in a class outside the form class. Create a subclass of Main with properties for the form and have it instantiated just prior opening the form. It should probably implement IDisposable and call the GC after it's not needed.

Closing the application will require serialization and saving to a file and/or a database.

Comment: thanks . I mean the closing application. Can you give me any example program for serialization ?

Comment: Follow @Gusdor's advice. XML would work well in this case. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751501.aspx

Comment: sorry i'm not getting the concept, how to use XML serialization for storing data which presents in the datagridview ?

Comment: It sounds like you aren't familiar with XML? XML is a file format for storing data. It's more than something I can tell you over a few comments. Read up on it, and try to implement it. If you have trouble with it, post another question.